# context.getContentResolver().query() Ignores Folder Created on the Fly

Tags: java, android

I've got an app that is copying image files from the phone's media directory to a directory the app is creating on the fly. However, when executing context.getContentResolver().query(), the folder I'm attempting to query returns a zero cursor.getCount(). I've spent a majority of the day on stackoverflow and other dev sites trying to figure this out, but I have yet to find any promising answers or clarification. I've also read up on content providers as well as the context class, however, there's nothing that seems to point to what I'm doing wrong.

To provide more specifics: in my code below, I have the following selectionArgs ("/%Event?"). As shown in the code, "Event" is the partial name of a directory contained in the path "/storage/emulated/0/PicShare/20140630_1624937_Event_Party at Rockert's!" that gets created on the fly. This returns a cursor with zero a count. HOWEVER, if I change the selectionArgs to "%/Pictures%" (which is a default image directory), it returns a cursor with images in that directory (which is what I would expect). So, to test whether my images and "%Event%" directory actually exist (other than verifying manually in the file system on the phone, which I did confirm), I added my "PicShare" and child directories under the "Pictures" directory, and when I run the app, the query ("%/Pictures") returns all pictures (as it did before) including the ones added on the fly by the app (as intended) located in "%PicShare/20140630_1624937_Event_Party at Rockert's!".

So, my question is, why can't I query my custom directory explicitly "%/PicShare%" like I can "%/Pictures%"? I've already confirmed the directory and images exist. I've got to be missing something. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, and I thank you in advance for your time.

```
public int GetEventImageCount(Context context)
{
    int result = 0;         
    // request only the image ID to be returned
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
    // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard where directory is created on the fly
    Cursor locCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                                          projection, 
                                                          "_data like ? ",
                                                          new String[] {"/%Event%"},  
                                                          null);

    if (locCursor != null)
    {
        result = locCursor.getCount();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the content provider doesn't know about the folder/files yet.
So I would suggest to call `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` or `ContentResolver.insert()` on just-copied pictures.

Comment: Thank you for the response (at least somebody did eventually). It's been awhile since I reported this, so when I get back to it, I'll provide an update.